# how to check which column values changed in 2 different excel files using alteryx

Tags: alteryx

There are 2 excel files named day1.xlsx and day2.xlsx having the same column structure. now I have to find which columns values are different and also show its previous value and the updated values. There is a ID column for Day1 file and Day2 file for the link up.

Below is an example:

[Below is image for day1 file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoZE7.png)

[Below is image for day2 file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxzun.png)

[Output should look like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWxXE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Load both files. For each of them separately, use the Transpose tool: in 'Key columns' check the "ID" column, in 'Data columns' check all your other columns. Then join both of the streams using the Join tool, joining on "ID" and "Name". Within the join tool, rename the "Value" column from the left input as 'Old value' and the "Value" column from the right input as 'New value'. This will give you the table you are looking for. You can then easily apply a Filter with the formula expression "[Old value]!=[New value]", which will only keep the columns that changed.